# JQuery returning empty arrays when using find() and children()

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js, traversal

I've been having some problems lately with traversal in jQuery. We have a web app, and there are multiple panels that each have a header and a body. In the header, there is a button that is used to expand/collapse the body of the panel. The panels are set up similar to this:

```
<div id="panel-1" class="panel">
  <div class="panel-header>
      <span>Header Text</span>
      <div class="toggle-expansion"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">...</div>
  <div class="panel-footer">...</div>
</div>

<div id="panel-2" class="panel"> ... </div> 
...
```

We are using Backbone.js to set up all the views, and there is a file named `base-panel-view.js` that all of the other panels extend from. I would like to put my function here if possible so I don't have to rewrite the function for every panel. Here is a snippet of the `base-panel-view.js` file:

```
...
       events: {
              ...
              "click .toggle-expansion" : "toggleExpansion"
       },
...
toggleExpansion: function() {
              var panel = $(this);                                   //Returns the entire panel
              var panelBody = panel.children(".panel-body");         //Should return the panel body
              var toggleButton = panel.find(".toggle-expansion");    //Should return the toggle button


              if(panelBody.hasClass("noDisplay")){
                     /* If the panel is collapsed, expand it */
                     panelBody.removeClass("noDisplay");
                     toggleButton.addClass("expanded").removeClass("collapsed");
              }else{
                     /* If the panel is expanded, collapse it */
                     panelBody.addClass("noDisplay");
                     toggleButton.addClass("collapsed").removeClass("expanded");                
              }             
       }
...
```

The `panel` variable gets set to the entire panel, which is what I expected, however `panelBody` and `toggleButton` are left empty. In the Chrome debugger, I am able to confirm that `panel` is containing the correct panel for whichever button I press, and I can see that the other variables are empty arrays. In the debugger, I can view `panel`'s array containing it’s children, which includes the panel body,  and header (which contains the button).

Is there something obvious that I’m doing wrong or not doing? I'm still relatively new to Javascript and jQuery, so it's entirely possible I'm messing up some fundamental step. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also I can confirm that the css is correct, since I made two buttons elsewhere that expand/collapse all panels, and I select the panel bodies there by using `$(".panel-body")`.  However for this question, I am only concerned with the panel for the corresponding button that was pressed.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `panel` is the actual panel? i'd expect it to be the element that was clicked, or, `<div class="toggle-expansion"></div>` which obviously has no children or descendants. What does `console.log(this.className)` give you?

Comment: @Kevin B 
At first I expected it to be `<div class="toggle-expansion"></div>` as well, but the debugger shows that `panel` is set to the panel. `console.log(this.className)` returns `undefined`, however in the Watch Expressions tab in the debugger, it reports `panel: e.fn.e.init[1]` and the first element of that array has `el: div#panel-1.panel`

Comment: this.className shouldn't be undefined though. What does this.id give you? The problem has nothing to do with .find or .children. The only way you could be seeing what you are seeing is if `this` isn't what you expect it to be or doesn't have the descendants you think it does.

Comment: `console.log(this.id)` returns undefined as well.

Comment: What does this[0].id give you? Maybe the plugin is incorrectly written. `this` shouldn't be a jQuery object.

Comment: `console.log(this[0].id)` throws a TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

Comment: I just noticed your previous edit. What exactly should `this` be?

Comment: `this` should be just the DOM Node itself, which would make `this.id` return `panel-1` if it was the panel. At this point, i can assure you that it both isn't the dom node, and it isn't a jQuery object. It's something else, maybe a backbone collection? i'm not very familiar with backbone.

Comment: I haven't considered if it is a backbone collection, but I'm not sure if that would make sense because I thought that .children() and .find() returned DOM elements. I'll try to look into if it is a Backbone collection and get back with you..

Comment: forget about .children and .find at this point, you need to get this.id to work for .children and .find to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I see now that you're using Backbone. Looking at [this](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents), you can see that `this` is the Backbone View, not a DOM element. To get the jQuery element, you have to use `this.$` as seen in the code in that link, not `$(this)`.

EIDT2: For any future readers, this was the problem, but not the exact solution. The OP was able to (as mentioned in the comments), replace this:

```
var panel = $(this);
```

with this:

```
var panel = this.$el;
```

And everything worked accordingly.

Comment: $(this).closest(".panel").children(".panel-body")

Comment: There's a bunch of ways to do it, I just wanted to show the most semantic one.

Comment: I tried both of these and `panel` was set to an empty array, as well as the other variables. I originally thought that `$(this)` would be the div on toggle-expansion, however it clearly is not.

Comment: Then there must be something that you're not showing us. How is that event getting bound to the object?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how Backbone.js works, but my working understanding is that whenever a click event happens on something with a class `toggle-expansion`, it will then look for a function in the file named `toggleExpansion` and then execute it. The function is being called correctly and is executed at the correct time.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the fact that you were using Backbone.js. I'm new to Backbone (like two days ago new), but I don't think that Backbone binds events in the same way as jQuery. I think that the `this` that you get doesn't point directly to the DOM element, but rather the Backbone view. Again, I'm really new to Backbone though.

Comment: Double post, but I think I was right. Try this: `this.$(".panel-body")`

Comment: So I believe it makes sense that `this` is pointing to the DOM element of the entire panel, which is the behavior that I'm seeing. If this is in fact the case, then why can't I set `panelBody` using `panel.children(".panel-body")`?

Comment: I edited my post. Judging by the Backbone documentation, you can't use jQuery like that. You have to access jQuery through the reference in the view.

Comment: if `this.id` isn't `panel-1`, then `this` isn't the DOM element of the entire panel.

Comment: @GJK, you close with `this.$(".panel-body")`. I tried `var panel = this.$el` and I was able to get the DOM element of the panel, and I was then able to set the other variables accordingly. Thank you so much! I never would have guessed that `this` was the Backbone view.

Answer (score 0):

```
(this).$element
```

In jQuery functions, `this` most often refers to the actual DOM element you're dealing with, whereas `$(this)` returns a jQuery object that wraps the element.

**Below is a sample code**

```
this.$('#clientsTable')
    .closest('.dataTables_wrapper')
    .find("div.toolbar")
    .html('<div class="table-tools-actions"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="addSelectedClients" onClick = addAllSelectedMembers()>' + "Add" + '</button></div>');
```

This above code takes my table is which in my case is ***clientsTable*** and searches for class ***dataTables_wrapper*** and then appends my HTML code block